# "-f" in apt-get -f install command?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Let me know word "-f" mentioned in apt-get -f install, what it actually denotes?

> apt-get -f install

Comment: perfect example for rtfm ...

Answer (score 3):

`-f` tells `apt-get` to fix broken packages by trying to locate and install missing dependencies.

Comment: `Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
 mailutils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Please help me on the above error. If possible, in the question also. https://askubuntu.com/questions/985925/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-mailutils-installation